# mounting server dir to local dir

Tags: mount, symbolic-link, sshfs

How can I mount server dir to local dir using the following command:

`sshfs -o follow_symlinks`

I have a hard time to configure it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
sshfs user@host:/remote_directory /local_directory
```

will help to connect remote directory to local dir